# SAS macro that calls other macro with unspecified parameters

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am trying to do a macro that takes other macros as an input, and these macros can have a different number of parameters. So imagine I have a macro:

```
%MACRO foo(text = );
%PUT &text.;
%MEND foo;
```

And I want to create a `call_macro` macro that calls `foo()`, specifying the text. The issue is that I might want to call another macro `fuu()` with other parameters.

I've thought of something like that:

```
%MACRO call_macro(macro = , args = );
%&macro.(&args.);
%MEND call_macro;
%call_macro(macro=foo, args='text=Hello');
```

Which obviouslly does not work, because I am calling `%foo('text=Hello')` instead of `%foo(text=Hello)`. Is there a way out of this?

(For context, I am trying to create a map function, used in R, for SAS. The objective would be to have a function `map` that takes a list of datasets, a function to be applied, and the parameters of that function, performs that function on all datasets)

Comment: Are you familiar with CALL EXECUTE? https://github.com/statgeek/SAS-Tutorials/blob/master/Turning%20a%20program%20into%20a%20macro.md

Comment: You can remove the quotes and it works.

Comment: I was not and it's useful, thank you! However, I'd like to send this macro to a parallel server, so all these functions are executed in parallel. If I didn't need the parallel functionality, that would be it.

Comment: Don't treat SAS like a functional language.  Program SAS programs using SAS style methods. If you want to work with data use data steps.  You can use the data step to generate the code you need and then run the code.  Either with CALL EXECUTE() or simple %INCLUDE of the generated text file.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to work with DATA in SAS then use SAS data steps and procedures.  This is true even if the data is actually metadata about code you want to run.

So if you have a dataset with three variables, REMOTE, MACRO and ARGS you can use that to generate a series of RSUBMIT/ENDRSUBMIT blocks to send the macro calls to each of the different parallel processes.  Then just use %INCLUDE to run the generated code.

```
filename code temp;
data _null_;
  set metadata ;
  by remote ;
  file code;
  if first.remote then put 'rsubmit ' remote ';' ;
  put '%' macro '(' args ');';
  if last.remote then put 'endrsubmit;' ;
run;
%include code / source2;
```

In reality the RSUBMIT statement might need to be more complex to really implement parallel execution, but the idea of how to generate the code from the metadata is the point.

Answer (score 2):

Just omit the quotes.

```
%MACRO call_macro(macro = , args = );
%&macro.(&args.);
%MEND call_macro;
%call_macro(macro=foo, args=text=Hello);
```

it would not work if you would have called your macro without equality signs
because in your call

```
%call_macro(foo, text=Hello);
```

the second argument would not be interpreted as having a value `text=Hello`, but as a parameter `text` with value `Hello`.

Comment: I think you meant that it wouldn't work if the CALL to the macro did not include the `args=`.  You can call a macro passing the parameter by name whether or not the macro definition also allows you to also pass the parameters by position.

Comment: Thanks, Tom, I did not know you can call a macro defined with positional parameters `%MACRO call_macro(macro, args);` using parameter names `%call_macro(macro = foo, args = text=Hello);`.

Answer (score 1):

If you code your dispatching macro with the `PARMBUFF` option, you do not need to embed your arguments within another parameter.  PARMBUFF supplies the macro the parameters, including any bounding parentheses.

Example:

Supply the dispatched macros arguments as first-order arguments to the dispatching macro.

```
%macro one (data=);
  %put INFO:   Macro:&SYSMACRONAME.  &=data;
%mend;

%macro two (data=, vars=);
  %put INFO:   Macro:&SYSMACRONAME. &=data &=vars;
%mend;

%macro three (data=, vars=, out=);
  %put INFO:   Macro:&SYSMACRONAME. &=data &=vars &=out;
%mend;

%macro dispatch (macro=) / PARMBUFF;
  %put INFO: -----;
  %put INFO: &SYSMACRONAME. &=SYSPBUFF; 
  %put INFO: &=macro;
  %if %length(&macro) %then %do;
    %let syspbuff = %sysfunc(prxchange(%str(s/,?\s*macro\s*=\s*\w+,?//i),-1,&syspbuff));
    %local invoke;
    %let invoke = &macro &syspbuff;
    %&invoke
  %end;
  %put INFO: -----;
%mend;

%dispatch(macro=one, data=foobar)
%dispatch(data=foobar, macro = one)
%dispatch(macro=two, data=foobar, vars=p q r)
%dispatch(macro=three, data=foobar, vars=p q r, out=snafu)

%one (data=x)
```

will log

```
INFO: -----
INFO: DISPATCH SYSPBUFF=(macro=one, data=foobar)
INFO: MACRO=one
INFO:   Macro:ONE  DATA=foobar
INFO:
INFO: -----
INFO: DISPATCH SYSPBUFF=(data=foobar, macro = one)
INFO: MACRO=one
INFO:   Macro:ONE  DATA=foobar
INFO:
INFO: -----
INFO: DISPATCH SYSPBUFF=(macro=two, data=foobar, vars=p q r)
INFO: MACRO=two
INFO:   Macro:TWO DATA=foobar VARS=p q r
INFO:
INFO: -----
INFO: DISPATCH SYSPBUFF=(macro=three, data=foobar, vars=p q r, out=snafu)
INFO: MACRO=three
INFO:   Macro:THREE DATA=foobar VARS=p q r OUT=snafu
INFO:
INFO:   Macro:ONE  DATA=x
```

Answer (score 1):

If you did want to do this then you need to protect the commas in the arguments to the submacro.  You could try macro quoting or actual quoting.  But it would be simplest to take advantage of the fact that commas inside of parentheses in a macro call do not get treated as indicating start of a new parameter.

So just pass the macro call without the `%` as the single argument to the CALL_MACRO macro.

```
%macro call_macro(arg);
  %put &=sysmacroname: &=arg ;
  %&arg.
%mend;

%macro test1(a,b=);
  %put &=sysmacroname: &=a &=b ;
%mend;

%macro test2(c,d,e);
  %put &=sysmacroname: &=c &=d &=e;
%mend;

%call_macro(test1(b=xyz,a=123))
%call_macro(test2(456,e=abc,d=89))
%call_macro(foo(text=Hello))
```

If for some reason CALL_MACRO needed to know the name of the macro it is going to call that could be extracted with a simple %SCAN() function call.

```
%local macroname;
%let macroname=%scan(&arg,1,());
```

Answer (score -1):

I worked it out. Set `args="par_1=val_1, par_2=val_2"` and then inside the macro, use `args=%sysfunc(COMPRESS(&args.,'"');`